# Cannot identify syntax errors

Tags: sql, sql-server

Newbie here. I'm trying to execute this line in sql server:

> CREATE TABLE dummy_driver

but I'm receiving the error message ***Incorrect syntax near 'dummy_driver'***. I can't seem to locate the error.

Additional code with line:

```
INSERT INTO Person (first_name, last_name)
Select f_name, l_name FROM driver;

CREATE TABLE dummy_driver

INSERT INTO dummy_driver
Select * from driver;
```

Comment: See CREATE TABLE syntax here:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. You're missing columns.

Answer (score 5):

You need to define the columns for your table in the Create statement. Your TSQL should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Person (first_name, last_name)
Select f_name, l_name FROM driver;

CREATE TABLE dummy_driver (First_Name varchar(25), last_name varchar(25))

INSERT INTO dummy_driver
Select first_name, last_name from driver;
```

You could also create your table on the fly with a [Select Into](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx):

```
SELECT first_name, last_name into dummy_driver
FROM driver
```

Comment: @DanielleStewart "didn't work" is not very helpful. What specifically didn't work and what error messages did you get

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you want whole schema and data copied from `driver` to `dummy_driver`. Instead of writing a `Create Table` statement for `dummy_driver`, you can simply write as :

```
SELECT * INTO dummy_driver FROM driver
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're just selecting all columns from `driver` into `dummy_driver`, you could also create it like this:

```
create table dummy_driver like driver;

insert into dummy_driver select * from driver;
```

Comment: Your `create table dummy_driver like driver;` will be supported in  MySql and DB2 only SQL Server will throw Error **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'like'.**